# Combined loops not working in Arduino

Tags: loops, if-statement, arduino, arduino-uno

I have an arduino code which is doing tasks like this:

```
while (a=='A')
{
   //do the task A
}

while (a=='B')
{
   //do the task B
}
```

These loop run correctly when they are run separately. But the problem comes when I try to combine both loops i.e.

```
void loop ()
{
   while (a=='A')
   {
     //do the task A
   }

   while (a=='B')
   {
     //do the task B
   }
}
```

Below is the code in full details:

```
void loop()                  
{
  ////// admin
  Serial.println("A or B");
  delay(500);
  char a = userinput();
  delay(500);
  while(a== 'A'){
    Serial.println("Type Your Starting ID Number...");
    while(1 ){
      while (Serial.available()==false);
      char e = Serial.read();
      if(isdigit(e)==false) break;
      startid = (startid*10)+(e - 48);
    }
    if(startid<=endid){
      for(pageid=startid; pageid<=endid; pageid++)
      {
        Serial.print("Your Biometric ID # is ");
        Serial.println(pageid);
        delay(2000);
        fingerenrollment(pageid);
        delay(2000);
        if(pageid == endid){
          Serial.println("......Memory Is Full....");    
          while(1);
        }
      }
    }
    else{
      Serial.println("Wrong Entry.......Please Reset Your Device.....");
      while(1);
    }
  } 
  ////// user
  while(a=='B'){
    lcd.print("WELCOME TO iPoll");
    delay(2000);
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.print("Place Your Thumb");
    delay(2000);
    lcd.clear();
    tempid = '\0';
    Serial.println("Place your Thumb For Authentication");
    delay(500);
    while(true){
      ID = fingerauthentication();
      delay(500);
      if(tempid != '\0') break;
    }
    delay(100);
    resp = userinput();
    delay(100);  
    lcd.clear();  
    datatrans(ID, resp);
  }
}
```

If you need any more help, I am here. Just comment.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be stuck in an infinite while loop. Try changing `while(a=='A')` and `while(a=='B')` to if(a=='A') and if(a=='B'). The void loop() method in Arduino automatically acts like an infinite while loop, looping through the code within it forever.

Answer (score 0):

`while (a == 'A')` loop is never ending because you never change the value of `a`. You need some `a = something;` somewhere in your code, or do what @Dan12-16 said. The same applies to `'B'`.

And a couple of tips to make your code easier to read (in my opinion). Instead of using `if (condition == false)`, you could use `if (!condition)`. Choose `while (1)` or `while (true)`, but don't mix them (I would choose the second one).